# How to implement table partitioning in Entity Framework Core with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core

I'm working on a project where I need to implement table partitioning based on a specific column (FinancialYear) in PostgreSQL using Entity Framework Core. I want to partition my table to improve performance and manage large datasets efficiently. However, I'm unsure about the best approach to achieve this within Entity Framework Core.

Could someone please provide guidance or examples on how to properly implement table partitioning in Entity Framework Core with PostgreSQL? Specifically, I'm looking for recommendations on:

- Defining table partitioning strategy within Entity Framework Core (if possible).
- Creating partitioned tables and managing partition creation.
- Routing data to appropriate partitions, possibly using triggers or other mechanisms.

Any insights, code examples, or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Googling 5 seconds [Issue: Support for table partitioning](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1035). 4 years...